# Why do I get this result when adding two rational numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, rational-number

Consider this short GHCi session:

```
ghci> import Data.Ratio
ghci> import Data.Word
ghci> 128 % 3 + 127 % 3 :: Ratio Word8
253 % 9
```

Why is the result `253 % 9` and not `255 % 3 (= 85 % 1)`?

That, really, is my question, but I'll be happy to elaborate.

---

First, if I remove the type, the result is what I'd expect:

```
ghci> 128 % 3 + 127 % 3
85 % 1
```

The type `Word8` seems important. I'm aware of potential integer overflow, but even so, I can't make sense of the result. E.g.

```
ghci> 128 + 127 :: Word8
255
```

There's no overflow here. That first happens at

```
ghci> 128 + 128 :: Word8
0
ghci> 128 + 129 :: Word8
1
```

If I divide by two instead of three, I can still comprehend the results:

```
ghci> 128 % 2 + 127 % 2 :: Ratio Word8
255 % 2
ghci> 128 % 2 + 128 % 2 :: Ratio Word8
128 % 1
ghci> 128 % 2 + 129 % 2 :: Ratio Word8
1 % 2
ghci> 129 % 2 + 129 % 2 :: Ratio Word8
1 % 1
```

Here `128 % 2 + 128 % 2` even produces `128 % 1` as one would hope. All of this seems to make perfect sense as 'normal' modulo-256 arithmetic, but then what happens when I work in thirds instead of halves? Why is the denominator `9`?

Comment: Yikes `Ratio Word8` is some kind of weird monster

Comment: @luqui Agreed. In case anyone was wondering, I was looking for an elegant way to do some arithmetic on 8-bit pixels for image processing. Turns out using `Ratio` isn't the way to go...

Comment: @MarkSeemann: I think a `Word32` might be sufficient, since the multiplication of two `Word8`s is always in the `Word16` range and thus then no overflow will occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because addition for the rationals is defined as

```
(x:%y) + (x':%y')   =  reduce (x*y' + x'*y) (y*y')
```

Since everything here is `Word8`, each individual operation is performed `mod 256`.

```
(128*3)   `mod` 256 = 128
(127*3)   `mod` 256 = 125
(128+125) `mod` 256 = 253
```

Comment: Thank you. Unrelated to my original question, but related to this answer: What does the `:` before the `%` indicate?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: I think the data constructor of the `Ratio` type?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Oh, yes, looking through the *source* for `Data.Ratio` I can see that it's there. I hadn't noticed it because it's not in the documentation, it seems.

Comment: `:%` is not in the Haskell 2010 specs. Data.Ratio doesn´t export this data constructor because it does not preserve the Ratio invariant that the value is normalized. It is exported from `GHC.Real` in case you need it for sole low level stuff or for Template Haskell.